# Rotate second monitor on the left side using shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, display-rotation

I had my second monitor on the right side of my laptop before, and I had no problem rotating the second monitor using keyboard shortcuts. The commands I use are:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left
```

and

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate normal
```

When the second monitor is rotated, it looks like this in Settings

[image]

Due to new apartment and table, I have to put my monitor now to the left side of the laptop. Now when I use the shortcut, it looks like this in the settings:

[image]

There is a gap between the monitors, and it feels terrible working with it. And if I move the second monitor in the settings to close the gap, then it works fine. But if I rotate the monitor back, the monitors overlap, and that's even more terrible.

Strangely if I change the orientation of the second monitor in the settings, not using the shortcuts, it works fine. I also noticed that in settings I have to set the second monitor to "Portrait Right", the opposite of the option in xrandr.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix my shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found it out myself. Now I add the flag `--left-of eDP-1` (my laptop display) to both commands, and it works beautifully. So:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left --left-of eDP-1
```

and:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate normal --left-of eDP-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'll probably be referring to this answer in the future.